# Installing ffpyplayer on Windows 10 for Python 310

Tags: python

I've spent a long time trying to installing ffpyplayer. Initial failures suggested that pkg-config, intl.dll and (possibly) libglib-2.0-0.dll were missing. So to keep things simple I downloaded them and put them in the Python Scripts folder. Now I am getting different errors when running `python -m pip install ffpyplayer`. There is a huge amount of output which I won't post on here at this stage but it basically suggests that libavcodec, libavdevice and other libav... elements are not found. I tried looking into how to obtain these for Windows but no success. One such suggestion was to get ffmpeg which I did but the package did not include these elements.

Comment: I've now run `pip install ffpyplayer` on another Windows 10 laptop and it appeared to have worked. In the distributions tests folder there is a test_play.py file with a line  `from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer`. I pasted that into the python interpretor and got the message `   from ffpyplayer.player.player import MediaPlayer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffpyplayer.player.player'`. ffpyplayer.player had been changed to ffpyplayer.player.player - i.e. not what I pasted. Running grepWin on site-packages/ffpyplayer reveals that 2 .pyd files have references to MediaPlayer.

Comment: Just to add to that - using my IDE (PyCharm), when I begin to key in the above `from ffpyplayer`... statement, it attempts to 'auto-complete' at every stage from when I begin to type 'ffplayer' right up to when I begin to type `MediaPlayer`. It's as though the IDE knows I have ffplayer and it's MediaPlayer, but Python itself doesn't. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: I have noticed that a file for the distribution named `__init__.py` has a line in it `from ffpyplayer.player.player import MediaPlayer`. Could this be why I am getting this problem. Is it at all likely that the distribution is wrong?